# How to make amchart's ammap for district level?

Tags: javascript, svg, amcharts, ammap

I am trying to make ammap for district level. First, one has to select state and then district. Upto state, it is fine. But, how to achieve the district level map?
I have svg for the district in india. I tried but couldn't make it.
[SVG here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Official_India_Map_with_Districts_2011_Census.svg)

[JSFIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/1mfz9xe5/)

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {

  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "projection": "miller",

  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "indiaLow",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": true,
    "selectedColor": "#CC0000"
  },
  "smallMap": {},
  "export": {
    "enabled": false,
    "position": "bottom-right"
  }
} );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/indiaLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: It's not enough to just have an svg file. You need to convert it to a structure that the library expects. Read [this tutorial](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/creating-custom-maps-for-javascript-ammap/) and follow the steps to convert it to the appropriate format.

Comment: Can you just give me an example of any country? I just need the structure of js file, how to make it so that i achieve state to district selection.

Comment: You have plenty of examples in the library's maps/js folder for how the resulting converted map js structure is supposed to look. Have you looked at them? If you're referring to an actual demo, the [drill down demo](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/drill-down-map/) pretty much shows how to link from one map to another. It's up to you to create the district map and link the country level to district level together.

Comment: Yes there are but none of them meet my requirements. Say there is world map. After selecting a country, the focus should be on the selected country and states of country should visible. Then we can select states in that country.

Comment: Let me try this one... Drill Down... Thank you